# Python Bokeh - upload a zip file and update the data source

Tags: python, file-upload, bokeh, zip

I want to use Bokeh FileInput and a button to upload a zip file, extract data from cvs and update the datasource. I have the code working for uploading zip file from local dir, extract and read csv file; but I am struggling to create a callback with Bokeh to get the same results as I get with the code bellow.

Please, any help is welcome. I have no idea how to solve this. Thank you!

Code for upload/read zip file (working):

```
import zipfile
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

file_name = 'somefile.zip'
path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

def upload():   
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as file:
        file.extractall(path = path)
        file.close()
if __name__ == '__main__': upload()

path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())+'/' + file_name[:-4] + '/*.csv'
for fname in glob.glob(path):
   df=pd.read_csv(fname, encoding='latin1', sep='\t')
```

Implementation with bokeh (callback to be defined):

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Div, Button, FileInput
from bokeh.layouts import layout, widgetbox

callbackUpload = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    ???

    }
    source.change.emit();
""")
#Div: heading
h_input = Div(text="""<h2>Upload your zip file</h2> """, max_height=40)

#File input
file_input = FileInput()

#Button: upload a new zip achive
button = Button(label="Upload", button_type="danger")
button.js_on_event(events.ButtonClick, callbackUpload)

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

layout = widgetbox(h_input, file_input, button)
show(layout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your zip-extracting Python code to work with Bokeh callbacks, you will have to use `bokeh serve` and `curdoc().add_root` instead of `show`.

Some example to get you started. Note that I don't use `Button` here to start the uploading process simply because when you select a file it will be uploaded automatically right away because the `FileInput.value` property is changed.

```py
import zipfile
from base64 import b64decode
from io import BytesIO

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Div, FileInput

h_input = Div(text="""<h2>Upload your zip file</h2> """, max_height=40)

file_input = FileInput()
source = ColumnDataSource(dict())


def value_changed(attr, old, new):
    data = b64decode(new)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(data)) as zf:
        # No need to call `zf.close()` - the `with` block does that for you.
        ...


file_input.on_change('value', value_changed)

show(column(h_input, file_input))
```

If you want to stick to `CustomJS` and avoid using `bokeh serve` at all costs, then you have to find some JavaScript library for zip archives extraction that works in browsers, attach it to your page (probably via a custom Bokeh template that can be passed to `save` - `show` doesn't support it right now), and use it within the JS code passed to `CustomJS`.

Comment: It's just an intermediate step until I find a solution how to handle the zip file. In the final setup, it will actually be a bokeh application  that integrates into a Django app.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Eugene! I thought I'd use the button for a better user experience. I'm a bit confused, don't understand at this moment how bokeh serve works alongside a Django server, thus I can't say if I want to stick to CustomJS.